# How to refer virtual path in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have created virtual directory in IIS under default web site. For example "VirtualPathTest".  It refer the physical path "d:\samplelocation\VTest"

How to refer the "VirutalPathTest" in asp.net page to store file and retrieve files in that location?

The above path is not inside asp.net application.

Any one assist me to handle.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by  `VirtualPathUtility`

```
Ex: VirtualPathUtility.GetDirectory(Request.Path)
```

if you are looking to get the domain name associated with your current request, along with the virtual path of the current application, then try like this :

```
Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + Request.ApplicationPath
```